# How to avoid 'buffering' input actions?

Tags: codenameone

Sometimes when the network or server is slow, the UI does not respond, and the user may click several times on various menus, or multiple times on the same. When finally the network responds, a succession of Forms flash across the screen corresponding to each previous click. It seems the UI is OK with this (e.g. only the last screen is active and the intermediate ones are not having any effect, so basically no functional impact).

However, it is visually quite disturbing, so I wondered if there is a way to avoid this, e.g. not 'buffer' the input actions, or somehow flush them all except the last. Or maybe some other solution?

Comment: This doesn't happen for any app I'm aware of. I think there's something seriously wrong with the flow you're describing but I'll need more information about what you actually did in terms of code.

Comment: Thanks Shai. I thought it was normal behavior (but a rare situation). I'll see if I can find a way to reproduce.